# Telerik UI for WPF: Dynamically change height of all rows in virtualized RadGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

Is it possible to change height of all rows of a virtualized RadGridView in runtime (e.g. when user clicks a button)?

Switching virtualization off is not an option due to size of the grid.

I tried to do this by changing height of every element of ChildrenOfType, but this affects only rows which are currently displayed.

```
foreach (var row in grid.ChildrenOfType<GridViewRow>())
{
    row.Height = 50;
}
```

I also tried using StyleSelector, but it affects only edited cell.

Comment: Create a style for `GridViewRow`.  Make it the default style for that type (at least within this particular `RadGridView`).  In the style, bind the `Height` property to some value in your view model.  Change the value in the view model when the user clicks the button or takes whatever action should change the height.

Comment: I should add that if you find that is not working you can explicitly set your new style in the GridView.    `RowStyle="{StaticResource MyGridViewRowStyle}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by setting

```
grid.RowHeight = 50
```

in the Loaded event handler in the parent item.